# CSS z-index how do I get the tree trunk to show in front of the ground?

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have this html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
  <title>Tree</title>
</head>
<body>
  <section class="picture">
    <div class="tree_trunk">

    </div>
  <section class="sky">

  </section>
  <section class="ground">

  </section>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

And Now I want to fill in the sky ground and tree trunk to be a responsive picture so that it grows and expands with browser. Currently however I cannot get the tree_trunk to come to the front.

```
.picture {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.sky {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 38%;
    width: 100%;
}
.ground {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 62%;
    top: 38%;
    background-color: green;
}
.tree_trunk {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 30px;
  height: 80px;
  color: brown;
  top: 22%;
  left: 40px;
}
```

Comment: if you want tree-trunk to be on top, why are you using a negative `z-index` on it?

Comment: yes @SamiaRuponti you are right,  Give background color to tree-trunk and z-index:1

Comment: I used z-index:1; and that failed as well

Answer (score 1):

Your tree trunk's `z-index` is nested within the `.picture` section.  So your tree's `z-index` is only going over other elements within your `.picture` div.

First of all, if you want an image to show over another, the `z-index` has to be higher.  Secondly, the elements have to be on the same level. So you will technically have to give your `.picture` element a `z-index` (and a `position`, `z-index` does not work without position.)

The only way to get around the nesting problem is to make your tree element `position:fixed;`